# Checkbox in gridview control

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, checkbox

I am using gridview to display labels, checkboxes, dropdown lists and textboxes

(see image)
i would like that some fields are hidden when the checkbox is unchecked and as soon as i check it, those hidden fields appear.(the fields to be hidden are the reason and the comments)

normally i assume i would use selectedindexchanged but since this is in a gridview i am not sure what i should do
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of OnCheckedChanged of check box

```
protected void chkbox_OnCheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      int selRowIndex = ((GridViewRow)(((CheckBox)sender).Parent.Parent)).RowIndex;
      CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)gridView.Rows[selRowIndex].FindControl("chkbox");

      if (cb.Checked)
      {
             // Find other control using FindControl and check the
      }
}
```

Comment: i added the method to my class and 

onCheckedChanged = "chkbox_OnCheckedChanged" to my aspx file
its still not going into the method, what should i do?

Comment: have you put Autopostback = true for checkbox and assign change event property to checkbox...just check this two thing

Comment: i did the autopostback, when you say 'assign change event property to checkbox' what do you mean?

Comment: Assign event handler to change event of checkbox that it

Comment: but its not even going to chkbox_OnCheckedChanged method, i think i might have declared it wrong in the aspx file? onCheckedChanged = "chkbox_OnCheckedChanged"

Comment: may be but this is the way to handle checkbox event.. when checkbox is part of gridview